# Dynamically inherit all Python magic methods from an instance attribute

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass, magic-methods

I ran into an interesting situation while working on a project:

I am constructing a class, which we can call `ValueContainer` which always will store a single value under a `value` attribute. `ValueContainer` to have custom functionality, keep other metadata, etc., however I would like to inherit all the magic/dunder methods (e.g. `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__repr__`) from `value`. The obvious solution is to implement all magic methods by hand and point the operation to the `value` attribute.

Example definition:

```
class ValueContainer:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ValueContainer):
            other = other.value
        return self.value.__add__(other)
```

Example behavior:

```
vc1 = ValueContainer(1)
assert vc1 + 2 == 3
vc2 = ValueContainer(2)
assert vc1 + vc2 == 3
```

However, there are two issues here.

1. I want to inherit ALL magic methods from `type(self.value)`, which would end up being likely 20+ different functions, all with the same core functionality (calling the `super` magic-method of `value`). This makes my every ounce of my body shiver, and shout "DRY! DRY! DRY!"
2. `value` can be any type. At the *VERY* least I need to support at least numeric types (`int`, `float`) and strings. The set of magic methods and their behaviors for numerics and strings are already different enough to make this a sticky situation to handle. Now when adding the fact that I would like the ability to store custom types in `value`, it becomes somewhat unimaginable to implement manually.

With these two things in mind, I spend a *long* time trying different approaches to get this working. The tough part comes from the fact that **dunder methods are class properties**(?), but **`value` gets assigned to an instance**.

Attempt 1: After `value` is assigned, we look up all the methods that start with `__` on the class `type(self.value)`, and assign the class dunder methods on `ValueContainer` to be these functions. This seemed to be a good solution at first, before realizing the doing this would now **reassign the dunder methods of `ValueContainer` for all instances**.

This means when we instantiate:

`valc_int = ValueContainer(1)`

it will apply all dunder methods from `int` to the `ValueContainer` **class**. Great!

...but if we then instantiate:

`valc_str = ValueContainer('a string')`

all the dunder methods for `str` will be set on the **class** `ValueContainer`, meaning `valc_int` would now try to use the dunder methods from `str`, potentially causing issue when there's overlap.

Attempt 2: *This is the solution I am currently using, which achieves the majority of the functionality that I'm after.*

Welcome, Metaclasses.

```
import functools

def _magic_function(valc, method_name, *args, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(valc.value, method_name):
        # Get valc.value's magic method
        func = getattr(valc.value, method_name)
        # If comparing to another ValueContainer, need to compare to its .value
        new_args = [arg.value if isinstance(arg, ValueContainer)
                    else arg for arg in args]
        return func(*new_args, **kwargs)


class ValueContainerMeta(type):
    blacklist = [
        '__new__',
        '__init__',
        '__getattribute__',
        '__getnewargs__',
        '__doc__',
    ]

    # Filter magic methods
    methods = {*int.__dict__, *str.__dict__}
    methods = filter(lambda m: m.startswith('__'), methods)
    methods = filter(lambda m: m not in ValueContainer.blacklist, methods)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        new = super(ValueContainer, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)

        # Set all specified magic methods to our _magic_function
        for method_name in ValueContainerMeta.methods:
            setattr(new, method_name, functools.partialmethod(_magic_function, method_name))

        return new


class ValueContainer(metaclass=ValueContainerMeta):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Explanation:

By using the `ValueContainerMeta` metaclass, we intercept the creation of `ValueContainer`, and override the specific magic methods that we collect on the `ValueContainerMeta.methods` class attribute. The magic here comes from the combination of our `_magic_function` function and [functools.partialmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod). Just like a dunder method, `_magic_function` takes the `ValueContainer` instance it is being called on as the first parameter. We'll come back to this in a second. The next argument, `method_name`, is the string name of the magic method we want to call (`'__add__'` for example). The remaining `*args` and `**kwargs` will be the arguments that would be passed to the original magic method (generally no arguments or just `other`, but [sometimes more](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)).

In the `ValueContainerMeta` metaclass, we collect a list of magic methods to override, and use `partialmethod` to inject the method name to call without actually calling the `_magic_function` itself. Initially I though just using `functools.partial` would serve the purpose since dunder methods are *class methods*, but apparently magic methods are somehow **also bound to instances** even though they are class methods? I still don't fully understand the implementation, but using `functools.partialmethod` solves this issue by **injecting the `ValueContainer` instance be called as the first argument in `_magic_fuction` (`valc`)**.

Output:

```
def test_magic_methods():
    v1 = ValueContainer(1.0)

    eq_(v1 + 4, 5.0)
    eq_(4 + v1, 5.0)
    eq_(v1 - 3.5, -2.5)
    eq_(3.5 - v1, 2.5)
    eq_(v1 * 10, 10)
    eq_(v1 / 10, 0.1)

    v2 = ValueContainer(2.0)

    eq_(v1 + v2, 3.0)
    eq_(v1 - v2, -1.0)
    eq_(v1 * v2, 2.0)
    eq_(v1 / v2, 0.5)

    v3 = ValueContainer(3.3325)
    eq_(round(v3), 3)
    eq_(round(v3, 2), 3.33)

    v4 = ValueContainer('magic')
    v5 = ValueContainer('-works')

    eq_(v4 + v4, 'magicmagic')
    eq_(v4 * 2, 'magicmagic')
    eq_(v4 + v5, 'magic-works')

    # Float magic methods still work even though
    # we instantiated a str ValueContainer
    eq_(v1 + v2, 3.0)
    eq_(v1 - v2, -1.0)
    eq_(v1 * v2, 2.0)
    eq_(v1 / v2, 0.5)
```

Overall, I am happy with this solution, **EXCEPT** for the fact that you *must specify which method names to inherit explicitly in `ValueContainerMeta`.* As you can see, for now I've taken the superset of `str` and `int` magic methods. If possible, I would love a way to dynamically populate the list of method names based on the type of `value`, but since this is happening before its instantiation, I don't believe that would be possible with this approach. If there are magic methods on a type that aren't contained within the superset of `int` and `str` right now, this solution would not work with those.

**Although this solution is 95% of what I am looking for, it was such an interesting problem that I wanted to know if anyone else could come up with a better solution, that accomplishes dynamic choosing of magic methods from the type of `value`, or has optimizations/tricks for improving other aspects, or if someone could explain more of the internals of how magic methods work.**

Comment: The magic methods are not "somehow bound to instances". Whenever you call instance method, then this instance is passed as first argument `self` to the called method. But you exposed `int.__add__` as `Container.__add__` - the implementation of `int.__add__` expects `int` or it's subclass as `self`. It gets `Container` instance instead because `Container(5) + 4` is resolved to `Container(5).__add__(4)` which is equivalent of `Container.__add__(Container(5), 4)`... That's why you had to implement `_magic_function()`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo The strange thing though is that `__add__` isn't present in the instance dictionary, it's only present on the class dictionary.

Comment: What's your specific question -- explain the quirks or implement those "5%"? What are those "5%"? The solution seems to already do everything that you want.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev the 5% I mentioned was being able to dynamically choose which methods to add from the type of value, including ones that may not be on the `int` and `str` class. And just see if anyone had a good explanation, or improvements to this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igor provided a very nice piece of code. You will probably want to enhance the method factory to support non-binary operations but, apart from that, in my opinion the use of a blacklist is not ideal in term of maintenance. You have to carefully review all possible special methods now, and check them again for possibly new ones with each new release of python.

Building on top of [Igor's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049128/3354661), I suggest another way making use of multiple inheritance. Inheriting from both the wrapped type and the value container lets the containers be almost perfectly compatible with the wrapped types while including the common services from the generic container. As a bonus, this approach makes the code even simpler (and even better with Igor's tip about `lru_cache`).

```
import functools

# container type superclass
class ValueDecorator:
    def wrapped_type(self):
        return type(self).__bases__[1]

    def custom_operation(self):
        print('hey! i am a', self.wrapped_type(), 'and a', type(self))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, super().__repr__())

# create and cache container types (e.g. IntContainer, StrContainer)
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=16)
def type_container(type_):
    name = f'{type_.__name__.title()}Container'
    bases = (ValueDecorator, type_)
    return type(name, bases, {})

# create or lookup an appropriate container
def value_container(value):
    cls = type_container(type(value))
    return cls(value)
```

Please note that unlike Sam and Igor's methods, which reference the input object in the container, this method creates a new subclassed object initialized with the input object. It is fine for basic values but may cause undesirable effects for other types, depending on how their constructor deals with copy.

Comment: update: reversed the order of base classes to have `repr()` work properly

Comment: Great idea! I completely agree, the blacklist is too fragile, and while OP's implementation of `_magic_function` handles unary operators, I think this approach is much better.

Comment: I also recommend `@functools.lru_cache`. I had forgotten about it when writing my answer, it's nicer than my hand-rolled cache, and makes your implementation of `type_container` a one-liner.

Comment: I didn't know the lru caching function, that's a clever enhancement here, thanks for this cool tip ! Answer updated, teamwork appreciated :)

Comment: This is very nice, @luciole75w ! One question, though: what if you want the *output* of operations involving ValueContainers to be ValueContainers themselves? For instance, you want `value_container(1) + value_container(2)` or even `value_container(1) + 2` to return an IntContainer, not an int. Are you back to dynamically creating magic methods?

Answer (score 4):

As you've correctly identified,

1. magic methods are discovered on the class, not on the instance, and
2. you have no access to the wrapped `value` prior to class creation.

With that in mind, I think it's impossible to force instances of the same class to overload operators differently depending on the wrapped value type.

One workaround is to dynamically create and cache `ValueContainer` subclasses. For example,

```
import inspect

blacklist = frozenset([
    '__new__',
    '__init__',
    '__getattribute__',
    '__getnewargs__',
    '__doc__',
    '__setattr__',
    '__str__',
    '__repr__',
])

# container type superclass
class ValueContainer:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.value)

# produce method wrappers
def method_factory(method_name):
    def method(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ValueContainer):
            other = other.value
        return getattr(self.value, method_name)(other)
    return method

# create and cache container types (instances of ValueContainer)
type_container_cache = {}
def type_container(type_, blacklist=blacklist):
    try:
        return type_container_cache[type_]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # e.g. IntContainer, StrContainer
    name = f'{type_.__name__.title()}Container'
    bases = ValueContainer,
    method_names = {
        method_name for method_name, _ in inspect.getmembers(type_, inspect.ismethoddescriptor) if
        method_name.startswith('__') and method_name not in blacklist
    }

    result = type_container_cache[type_] = type(name, bases, {
        n: method_factory(n) for n in method_names})
    return result

# create or lookup an appropriate ValueContainer
def value_container(value):
    cls = type_container(type(value))
    return cls(value)
```

You can then use the `value_container` factory.

```
i2 = value_container(2)
i3 = value_container(3)
assert 2 + i2 == 4 == i2 + 2
assert repr(i2) == 'IntContainer(2)'
assert type(i2) is type(i3)

s = value_container('a')
assert s + 'b' == 'ab'
assert repr(s) == "StrContainer('a')"
```